# Yule-Walker PSD Estimate of an AR Process

Tags: python, power-spectral-density

I am trying to implement a Yule-Walker PSD estimation in Python but my results are not up to the expectations. In MATLAB, I would normally implement my functionality as follows:

```
pxx = pyulear(x,order,nfft)
```

The process is the same in python using the [Pyuler module](http://www.thomas-cokelaer.info/software/spectrum/html/user/ref_param.html#spectrum.yulewalker.pyule) as follows

```
data = (data - data.mean()) / data.std() # Normalize to a zero mean signal
order =16
p = pyule(data, order, NFFT=256)
p.run()
Pxx= p.get_converted_psd(sides='onesided')
Pxx =np.abs(Pxx)**2 # I want to plot the square of the PSS
Fxx=p.frequencies(sides='onesided')
plot (Fxx, Pxx)
show()
```

I tried the following similar approach but I am getting a wrong output as well

```
ar, P, k = aryule(data, order, norm='biased')
psd = arma2psd(ar)
# Get just one side of the psd
Pxx = psd[len(psd):len(psd) / 2:-1]
Pxx =np.abs(Pxx)**2
plot(Fxx, Pxx)
```

Compared to the expected values (from a trusted third party software), my script's output is on average 7587764 times bigger than the expected. When I plot my expected vs the actual value, I get the following picture 
[image]
My question are:

1. What I am doing wrong?
2. The documentation says that the sequence should be a white noise process of zero mean and variance. Can this be achieved this approach

> ```
>       data = (data - data.mean()) / data.std()
> ```

2. Does anyone know of any Python modules that implement the Yule-Walker PSD like MATLAB does?

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE!  It's not clear to me what is wrong? Can you please include a plot showing the expected output and the output you actually get?

Comment: @PeterK. thanks for your reply. I do not understand what's wrong myself. I have update my post to reflect your requested changes. Also, for the record, the data I am using can be accessed at this link http://textuploader.com/d5hqz.

Comment: @PeterK. I am looking forward to your help. One last detail is that the data a sequence of Interbeat Intervals from an ECG signal; thus, it is not uniformly sampled; I used a cubic linear interpolation using `scipy import interpolate` before estimating the spectra